# I'm trying to get the names of the tracks that are being stored in a JSONData using a loop

Tags: json, swift, api

Here's the code.

```
func callFire(url:String) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
}

func parseData(JSONData: Data) {
    do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? JSONStandard {
            if let items = tracks["items"]{
                for i in 0..<items.count {
                    let item = items[i] as! JSONStandard
                    let name = item["name"] as! String
                    trackNames.append(name)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This is where I'm getting an error "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'"

**let item = items[i] as! JSONStandard**

Comment: show your server response

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using JSONStandard? Just turn that node into a Map or Array. If it's a map, you would do:

```
if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? [String: Any]
```

then you can pull things out by name, e.g.:

```
let name = tracks["name"] as? String
```

BTW, this is from [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) Apple recently published about handling JSON.

Comment: JSONStandard is a typealias of [String : AnyObject], tried using [String : Any] but it says conditional binding must be a Optional type not [String : Any]

Comment: Did you make that alias? Doesn't make much sense to me because each node is either an array or map. As the guide states, also: sometimes you know the type and thus don't use Any.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your `parseData(JSONData: Data)` should probably look like

```
var trackNames = [String]()

func parseData(JSONData: Data) {
    do {
        if let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any],
             let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? [String: Any],
                 let items = tracks["items"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    trackNames.append(contentsOf: items.map{$0["name"] as! String})
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Valid JSON always contains fields of `[String:Any]` where `Any` can be again `[String:Any]` representing a nested dictionary.
Here is the test:

```
let json = "{\"tracks\":{\"items\":[{\"name\":\"a\"},{\"name\":\"b\"},{\"name\":\"c\"}]}}";

var trackNames = [String]()

func parseData(JSONData: Data) {
    do {
        if let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any],
             let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? [String: Any],
                 let items = tracks["items"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    trackNames.append(contentsOf: items.map{$0["name"] as! String})
                    print(trackNames) // prints ["a", "b", "c"] 
                    //self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

parseData(JSONData: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: That doesn't give me any errors but it won't append the items into the cell labels.

Comment: can you provide a simple example of your json?

Comment: Okay this is getting weird. Now that error is gone and I'm getting an error on this line **let itemName = item["name"] as! String**, it says "Type Any? has no subscript members. I tried cleaning the project and reopening it :/

Comment: thats because type `Any` or `Any?` should be casted to dictionary/array to have subscript